# If $P$ is a polynomial with $|P(1)| = \max\limits_{|z| =1} |P(z)|$, then its root on the unit circle is separated away from 0

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $P(z)$ be a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ such that $$|P(1)| = \max\limits_{|z| =1} |P(z)|.$$
Furthermore let $z_0 = e^{i\varphi_0}$, $\varphi_0 \in [-\pi,\pi]$ be a root of $P$ on the unit circle.

I want to prove that $|\varphi_0| \geq \pi /n$. Also, by my intuition, if this becomes an equality, $P(z)$ would be a multiple of $1+z^n$. Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "nontrivial" polynomial of degree $n$ ?

Comment: It means that P is not just the zero polynomial, in that case every point on the unit circle is a root so that the statement cannot be true.

Comment: Well, the zero polynomial is not of degree $n$. I think "nonzero" would be clearer than "nontrivial"

Comment: Yes, i have edited it.

Comment: Is this is a homework question? Can you provide some context or motivation ?

Comment: No, i met this while reading a paper. The result is cited from the book On rational polynomials of P. Turán, however i couldn't find the book.

Comment: Don't know if it helps, the book was published in 1946..

Comment: I could only find [a review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=18268), but didn't find the original paper.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I already wrote how to get free access to the paper...

Comment: @GabrielRomon The page you gave is automatically redirected to another page saying *The page you tried to access requires you to log in the system first. It appears that you either didn't log in, or you were not doing anything on the ACTA site for too long. Please click on the below link to be taken to login pages.*

Comment: @GabrielRomon Also I didn't find that paper on JSTOR.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Alright, my bad. Go to http://pub.acta.hu/acta/customer/searchArticle.ftl?noDataSet=true , type "rational polynomial" in the field "Word in title:" and you'll get access.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Thanks a lot! The new link works and is really helpful.

Comment: You surely mean "separated from $1$", not from $0$.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT. Mulpiplying on a constant, we may assume wlog that $P(1)=1$.
Consider the function $$f(t)=\frac{1}{2}\left( P(e^{it})+\overline{ P(e^{it})}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left( P(e^{it})+P^*(e^{-it})\right),$$
where $P^*$ is the polynomial with complex conjugate coefficients.

This $f$ is an entire function of exponential type $n$, real on the real line, and and $|f(t)|\leq1$ on the real line, $f(0)=1$.

For such functions we have a generalization of Bernstein's inequality
due to Szego and Boas:
$$f'^2+n^2f^2\leq n^2,$$
which we rewrite as
$$|f'|\leq n\sqrt{1-|f|^2}.$$
Now define $g(t)=\arcsin f(t)$.

Suppose that $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=1$, and $0<f(t)<1$ for $t\in(a,b)$. Then $g$ is well defined (with the principal branch of arcsin) 
and analytic on $(a,b)$, and $g(a)=0,\; g(b)=\pi$. 
Thus in view of our inequality above
$$\pi\leq\int_a^b|g'(t)|dt\leq\int_a^b \frac{|f'(t)|}{\sqrt{1-f^2(t)}}dt\leq n|b-a|.$$
So $|b-a|\geq\pi/n,$
as requested. The statement on the case of equality follows from the case of equality in Szego's inequality.

Refs.

Szegö, Schriften der Königsberger gelehrten Gesellschaft, Naturwissenschaftliche
Klasse, Fünftes Jahr 4 (1928), p. 69.

R. Duffin and A. Shaeffer, Some inequalities for functions of exponential type, Bull AMS, 43 (1937), 554. (Freely available online.)

EDIT. Further research shows that the result is not new: it was proved in

MR0018268
Turán, P.
On rational polynomials. 
Acta Univ. Szeged. Sect. Sci. Math. 11, (1946). 106–113.